# Why can't I appoint a broker?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I am new to DF and I have only played a few games. In my latest game, I am trying to trade with a caravan for a new anvil. However, there is a problem. I can't appoint a Broker. In my other games, I started out with a Leader and a Chief Doctor. The Broker skill was always available for when I chose to appoint one.

When I go to the [n]oble screen, I just see the expedition leader. There are no other positions on the list; not even the Chief Doctor.

Any idea why this is?

Comment: Well, it looks like I CAN trade without a broker, but it would still be nice to know why I can't access my nobles anymore.

Comment: Do you _have_ an expedition leader?  If not, can you appoint one?

Comment: Have you been messing with the dwarf entity's raws? You may have broken the tags that make nobles work; in particular, if you damaged the expedition leader entry, later entries may not be read properly.

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't show any noble titles other than the leader I'd say something is corrupt in your game.

Try reinstalling from the site, however if this doesn't work you may need to dump your save file (or spend some time editing it manually to fix the enity_raws again.